# Page View Controllers with scroll effect vs. UIScrollView with Paging Enabled

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I don't understand what's difference between Page View Controllers with scroll effect and UIScrollView with Paging Enabled.

If they are have the some scroll effect, which one do you think better?

Answer (score 0):

Both are same visually but in pageview controller we have to pass the view controller for the delegates before and after and you can also use page curl effect in page view controller..